# Sorting object based on nested object property?

Tags: php

Given this possible object structure (via var_dump):

```
stdClass Object
(
    [jobs] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => fbb3d
                    [title] => TRS Trainer
                    [full_title] => TRS Trainer - Moorhead
                    [shortcode] => 2330A8E687
                    [code] => 
                    [state] => published
                    [department] => CSD Contact Centers
                    [url] => https://csd.workable.com/jobs/1029739
                    [application_url] => https://csd.workable.com/jobs/1029739/candidates/new
                    [shortlink] => https://csd.workable.com/j/2330A8E687
                    [location] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [country] => United States
                            [country_code] => US
                            [region] => Minnesota
                            [region_code] => MN
                            [city] => Moorhead
                            [zip_code] => 
                            [telecommuting] => 
                        )

                    [created_at] => 2019-05-21T21:03:39Z
                )
        )
)
```

Via var_export:

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'jobs' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'id' => 'fbb3d',
       'title' => 'TRS Trainer',
       'full_title' => 'TRS Trainer - Moorhead',
       'shortcode' => '2330A8E687',
       'code' => NULL,
       'state' => 'published',
       'department' => 'CSD Contact Centers',
       'url' => 'https://csd.workable.com/jobs/1029739',
       'application_url' => 'https://csd.workable.com/jobs/1029739/candidates/new',
       'shortlink' => 'https://csd.workable.com/j/2330A8E687',
       'location' => 
      stdClass::__set_state(array(
         'country' => 'United States',
         'country_code' => 'US',
         'region' => 'Minnesota',
         'region_code' => 'MN',
         'city' => 'Moorhead',
         'zip_code' => NULL,
         'telecommuting' => false,
      )),
       'created_at' => '2019-05-21T21:03:39Z',
    ))
  ),
))
```

What'd the best way to sort by region be?  I tried using usort like so:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a->jobs->location->region, $b->jobs->location->region);
}
$response = json_decode($response);
usort($response, "cmp");
```

But after decoding the JSON response into an object then running it through usort, it doesn't come out sorted.  I don't think I'm doing this right, and coding sorting algorithms isn't my strongest forte.

I did consider trying `sort`, but realized it wasn't going to cut it due to nested objects.  I went looking on Google for other examples to figure it out, but it appears most options out there are for arrays whereas I'm working with an object.

Comment: I don't see a `jobs` key  in your object. Perhaps you should just be sorting on `$a->location->region`?

Comment: Fixed paste, read again. My fault for not pasting whole structure.  I tried to edit quickly to correct, but you're quicker!

Comment: Jobs is an array. You can select the element at index 0 if there is only one

Comment: Also, it would be so much easier for use if you used `var_export()` to show us the data.

Comment: There's about 40 jobs in the array.

Comment: You probably want to sort `$response->jobs`, not `$response` (in which case you don't need the `->jobs` part in your comparison function).

Comment: What are you trying to sort? The `jobs` array or something a level above?

Comment: Edited original post and added var_export, @Dharman -- and yes, the jobs array

Comment: `usort($response->jobs, "cmp");` and then in your sort start with `$a->location->region`

Comment: use `$a->location->region` and `usort($response->jobs, 'cmp')`

Comment: @Dharman snap! :-)

Comment: That did it, it's sorting properly once I adjusted usort to $response->jobs and removed `->jobs` from `cmp` function.   Thanks @Jeto, @dharman, and @nick!

What would be the best way to handle this post now that my issue has been resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you explained in the comments you want to sort an array which is a property of your main object. To do that you can pass that property to `usort()` instead of the whole object, and then sort comparing `$a->location->region`.

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a->location->region, $b->location->region);
}
$response = json_decode($response);
usort($response->jobs, "cmp");
```